# Admob a lot request but no impressions

Tags: android, admob

I have four apps using admob banner to earn some extra cash. This issues happen on two of my latest release app. The first one got 200 request but only 4 impression. Another one get more worst, take a look at the screen shot below

[image]

When I first release the app to playstore, I got almost 90% match rate. But this happen about a week ago, which i got alot of request but no impressions. So I started asking my friend to download the app and see wether the ad banner do show up. None of the ads show up on their mobile. Did anyone experience this kind of issues?

Comment: You can get the error code in `onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad` method. If you still don't get why it happens you can get help from the support. When you apply, you accept to use only test ads. It maybe happened because most of the ads where launched by you in the end

Comment: Hi I received an error code of 0. Which means internal error.

Comment: Then you will have to compare the way you display ads with google ad banner sample on Git hub : [https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ads/tree/master/admob/BannerExample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ads/tree/master/admob/BannerExample)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be problem on your account **or** on your implementation.

To rule out the implementation issue, use test ids on your test devices: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads

Using test IDs you can narrow the problem:

• If you don't see any ads with test IDs, you have a problem with your code.

• If you see ads with test IDs and don't see with real IDs, you have a problem on your account. I recommend creating new IDs to your banners. If this doesn't it's very likely you have an issue on your account, so I suggest you to contact AdMob support.

Comment: Thank you! I kinda resolve the issues from your suggestion

Comment: @user3651999 how did you fix this problem? I am also facing similar issue, my request number is going high but I can't see any impressions. Did you contact support?

Comment: @Ani Did you try using test ids provided by Google? With these IDs you can rule out code issues.

Comment: @tomDev Test Ads work on test device and emulator. Only the real ads are not working. I don't know how to get it fixed

Comment: I'm also with the same problem. Test IDs work perfectly, but zero impressions on production. And it was working just fine on production for about a week, then suddenly it stopped working. Anybody has any idea what to do?

Comment: It doesn't work on real devices with real ads id! I can't reach to Google support, how one can get it fixed could share it please?

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have set up app-ads.txt correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this problem happens when you just recently started your account and you haven't verified your address or bank account!

After 30 to 50 dollars you need to verify your physical address. sometimes you don't get the code very soon and you need to apply for it couple of times, over this time your impression may stop and gets very low! after verification it takes one or two weeks to get back to normal situation.